# Can someone explain to me what are the difference between this two results?

Tags: android, testing

I'm doing tests in android studio for a tutorial and the test results show me this:

```
expected:<2,00[ ]$> but was:<2,00[ ]$>
Expected :2,00 $
Actual   :2,00 $
```

I'm a bit confused ! both are the same string....

EDIT:

This is the method i'm testing

```
@VisibleForTesting
internal fun calculateTip(
    amount: Double, percent: Double = 15.0, roundUp: Boolean): String{

    var tip = percent / 100 * amount
    if (roundUp)
        tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
}
```

This is the test assertion:

```
@Test
    fun calculate_20_percent_tip_no_roundup() {
        val amount = 10.00
        val tipPercent = 20.00
        val expectedTip = "2,00 $"
        val actualTip = calculateTip(amount = amount, percent = tipPercent, false)
        assertEquals(expectedTip, actualTip)

    }
```

Comment: For anyone attempting to reproduce, the currency locale which recreates the problem is "fr", "CA" .  (It can be reproduced using that locale but passes if for example it's "en" "CA")

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to shed light on the difference...

In order to recreate I had to use the locale

```
java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance( Locale("fr", "CA" )).format(2.00)
```

In the run log for the test it will show:

[image]

And if you click on `Click to see difference` it shows:

[image]

So the `NumberFormat` for that particular locale currency introduces the [`NBSP`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-typography/nbsp.html).  Unfortunately cannot explain *why* it would do that.

MFP:

```
@Test
fun test_currencyComparison() {
    val expected = "2,00 $"
    val actual = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance( Locale("fr", "CA" )).format(2.00)
    println("$expected $actual")
    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

One way to overcome this in your case would be to use the same `NumberFormat` to generate the expected:

```
@Test
fun calculate_20_percent_tip_no_roundup() {
    val amount = 10.00
    val tipPercent = 20.00
    val expectedTip = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(2.00)
    val actualTip = calculateTip(amount = amount, percent = tipPercent, false)
    assertEquals(expectedTip, actualTip)

}
```

Comment: it's kinda strange since both string are visually the same except for that NBSP